# symfony2 UniqueEntity with many to one field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, unique-constraint

I need to create unique constraint with 2 fields of my entity ('number' and 'mag'), but mag is many to one field.

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Magazine", inversedBy="magazine_numbers")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="magazine_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
public $mag;
```

I tried to do it like this

```
/**
* MagazineNumber
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Creative\NicrpBundle\Entity\MagazineNumberRepository")
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"magazine_id", "number"}, message="There already is such a magazine number.")
*/
class MagazineNumber
```

But it made exception

> The field 'magazine_id' is not mapped by Doctrine, so it cannot be validated for uniqueness.

I tried doing it this way

```
* @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={
*     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="magazine_number_uk", columns={ "magazine_id", "number"})
* })
```

But it made exception

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2-1' for key 'magazine_number_uk'
```

My goal is to show my message on unique constraint.

Comment: Can you upload the Entity with at least the relevant fields? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using varnames instead of columns names.

```
/**
* MagazineNumber
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Creative\NicrpBundle\Entity\MagazineNumberRepository")
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"mag", "number"}, message="There already is such a magazine number.")
*/
class MagazineNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

try make this:

```
* @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={
*     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="magazine_number_uk", columns={ "mag", "number"})
* })
```