# Symfony2/Doctrine UniqueEntity on ManyToOne entity ignored

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, unique-constraint

I have "roles" associated to "projects".
I don't care if a role name is duplicated, but what I want to make sure is that for each project the role name cannot be duplicated.

Here is what I thought should work:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Role.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\RoleRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="roles")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name","project"}, message="Duplicated role for this project")
 */
class Role
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $description;

...
other fields
...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project")
 */
protected $project;
}
```

According to the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#fields) that's exactly what I need:

> This required option is the field (or list of fields) on which this
>   entity should be unique. For example, if you specified both the email
>   and name field in a single UniqueEntity constraint, then it would
>   enforce that the combination value where unique (e.g. two users could
>   have the same email, as long as they don't have the same name also).

The constraint is simply ignored (I mean that if I try to have the same role name for the same project, it stores the duplicated role name and projectID).

What am I missing?

EDIT: after I updated the DB with "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" I tried to generate the error directly with SQL, but no exceptions were thrown. Now, I don't know if this "UniqueEntity" validation is done at DB level or it's Doctrine's validator.

EDIT2: I tried to have only one field ("name") and the validation works properly (only on that field of course). **I also tried to have validation on the fields "name" and "description" and it works!!! So basically it does not validate if the field to be validated is the ID pointing to another table.**

Anyways, here is the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/role/create/{projectID}", name="role_create")
 */
public function createRoleAction(Request $request, $projectID)
{
    $prj = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Project')->findOneById($projectID);

    $role = new Role();
    $form = $this->createForm(new RoleFormType(), $role);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
        {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $role->setProject($prj);
        $em->persist($role);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('hr_manage', array('projectID' => $projectID)));
        }

return $this->render('Role/createForm.html.twig', array('projectID' => $projectID, 'form' => $form->createView(),));
}
```

The validation is not performed, and the entity persisted on DB, with the "project" column pointing at the right project. Here is a snapshot of the 2 relevant fields:
[image]

Here is the RoleFormType (an extract of relevant fields):

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RoleFormType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // add your custom field
    $builder->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('description', 'text')
            ...lots of other fields, but "project" is not present as it's passed automatically from the controller
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

}

public function getName()
{
    return 'role';
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Role',));
}

}
```

Comment: Did you `use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;`?

Comment: Unfortunately I did :/. I'm wondering if it can work on ManyToOne fields (it should as you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282361/symfony2-uniqueentity-with-many-to-one-field?rq=1 )

Comment: Did you [enable annotations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#configuration)?

Comment: Yep. If I make a change on the role class and run "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" it properly updates the DB so we are ok on that respect.

Comment: Doctrine schema has nothing to do with annotations enabled for validation. I'm asking if you enabled annotations for validation, since from that link: "The Symfony validator is enabled by default, but you must explicitly enable annotations if you're using the annotation method to specify your constraints." However if you've followed the steps I've linked then my troubleshooting is satisfied.

Comment: I do confirm I have "validation:      { enable_annotations: true }" under "framework:". I also checked if the config_dev.yml overrides the parameter and it doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are not actually validating the entity to check for the unique constraint violation.  When you call `$form->isValid()`, it does call the validator for the `Role` entity since you passed that as the form's data class.  However, since `project` is not set until after that, no validation occurs on the `project` field.

When you call `$em->persist($role);` and `$em->flush();` this simply tells Doctrine to insert the entity into the database. Those 2 calls do **not** perform validation on their own, so the duplicates *will* be inserted.

Try setting the project before creating the form instead:

```
$role = new Role();
$role->setProject($prj);

$form = $this->createForm(new RoleFormType(), $role);
```

Now project will be set on the entity, so when `$form->isValid()` is called the Symfony validator will check for uniqueness.

If that doesn't work, you'll want to add a `project` type to the form as a `hidden` field as well so it's passed back, but I don't think that will be necessary.

The other thing I would state is that you definitely want to add the unique constraint on your database itself - this way even if you try to insert a duplicate, the database will thrown an exception back to you and not allow it, regardless of your code.

Comment: Yes, moving the $role->setProject($prj) before the $form->isValid() did the trick! It makes all the sense. Thank you!

Comment: It's funny how sometimes you can go back and forth on all this code, digging way too deep and looking for issues when the solution is so simple

Comment: I still have a little issue here: if projectID is not null it works like a charm, but if it's null (which can be) the validation is not performed as expected. Clues?

Comment: I tried @UniqueEntity(fields={"name","project"}, ignoreNull="false", message="Duplicated role for this project") both with and without quotes around "false", but it's not working :/

Comment: Ok, it's an issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/228ef22f32baa9c36f51d2286b962300bee704e1 . Will wait for the update to come to a stable release.

Comment: Looks like that issue is fixed though?  It appears like you want `ignoreNull` set to **true** though, not false

Comment: Actually not. It's been fixed in dev only a few days ago. It will take until the next release to be fixed. And no, ignoreNull true is the default which did not work, I need the ignoreNull to be false.

Comment: Interesting - I wonder if that 2.3 fix is for all versions or if it's already fixed in later Symfony versions.  Thanks for informing me.